# Reduce database item count on Update

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an **Inventory Management System** winform `C#`.

When I sell something I the totla count should get reduced in database.

```
SqlDataAdapter sd3 = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "UPDATE Stock SET Vcount=Vcount-('"+textBox4.Text+"') WHERE id=('"+textBox4.Text+"')", conn);
```

But it does not.

Comment: Please edit your question, choose a shorter title, add problem description to the question, format the code, tell what exception or wrong behavior has happened, tell what is the expected behavior. Take a look at [ASK].

Comment: do you also have some code which executes this query?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove () and ' because stock and id are integer:

```
SqlDataAdapter sd3 = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE Stock SET Vcount=Vcount- "+textBox4.Text+" WHERE id="+textBox4.Text, conn);
```

Comment: "because stock and id are integer" it sounds like a valid assumption, but what makes you so sure? do you know the table layout? ;)

Comment: we often make the stock and id are integer :)